# Add context menu in a datagrid view in a winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to show a Context Menu when you right click a Menu Item in a DataGridView ? 
I would like to add  delete in the menu so that the entire row can be deleted .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: +1 for asking exactly what I was about to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to **Miguel** answer
I think this will be easy to implement like this

```
    int currentRowIndex;
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    }  
    private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex]);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to create a context menu with a 
"delete row" option in the designer. Then assign the DGV (Data Grid View)'s ContextMenuStrip property to this context menu.

Then double click on the delete row item, and add this code:

```
DGV.Rows.Remove(DGV.CurrentRow);
```

You'll also need to add a MouseUp event for the DGV that allows the current cell to change when you right click it:

```
private void DGV_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // This gets information about the cell you clicked.
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.HitTestInfo ClickedInfo = DGV.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    // This is so that the header row cannot be deleted
    if (ClickedInfo.ColumnIndex >= 0 && ClickedInfo.RowIndex >= 0)

    // This sets the current row
    DataViewMain.CurrentCell = DGV.Rows[ClickedInfo.RowIndex].Cells[ClickedInfo.ColumnIndex];
}
```

Comment: +1 for *"Then assign the DGV (Data Grid View)'s **ContextMenuStrip property** to this context menu."*

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old, but maybe someone will still have use for this. There is an Event for this, `CellContextMenuStripNeeded`. The following code works perfectly for me and seems less hacky than the `MouseUp` Solution:

```
private void DGV_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DGV.ClearSelection();
        DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
        e.ContextMenuStrip = MENUSTRIP;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also there is no need to check for `if (e.RowIndex >= 0)` since the event is triggered by a Cell that is for suew in a row or in another. So `e.RowIndex >= 0` will always be true.

Comment: Note that this is behavior is different from what happens with the MouseDown event and others similar: in that case  the event is triggered also when the user operates with the mouse on the header row and `e.Rowindex = -1` is given.

Comment: CellContextMenuStripNeeded won't fire if the rows are not databound