# How can i create a context menu in c# in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

I have written a datagridview with a couple of columns to store data of a product, now i want to be able to right click any row and have a context menu appear with the options delete and copy. Copy should have the same functionality as if I press Ctrl+C. Any help would be appreciated. Im using C# and WinForms. I have never done context menus before, so I would be thank full for any hint or link to further readings.

Cheers

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201816/add-context-menu-in-a-datagrid-view-in-a-winform-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this problem on stack overflow, it should answer your query

[Add context menu in a datagrid view in a winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201816/add-context-menu-in-a-datagrid-view-in-a-winform-application)