# How to remove the first "column" from a datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I'm trying to use a datagrid in my VB application. But I'm running into a problem. I keep getting this column, shown below highlighted in red, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

What property do I use to get rid of this column?

[image: A Window with a datagrid in it]

Further more, how can I create a context menu for when I right click on a grid row.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [`RowHeaderVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.rowheadersvisible.aspx) property.

And about context menu, you should check that questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201816/add-context-menu-in-a-datagrid-view-in-a-winform-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450992/c-sharp-winforms-datagridview-contextmenu-apear-at-2nd-right-click-not-at-fir)