# How I can use windows's SendTo option in my C# Application using datagridview

Tags: c#, sendto

i am listing files from directories on click on that specific folder name, when files show in datagridview. Now using context menu i want to add this sendto option in that context menu and want to send that file to any removable media.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcuts to programs that you see in windows 'send-to' menu are stored in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` folder.

Read the contents of this folder and show the options in your Grid's context menu.

The shortcuts are `.LNK` files. Resolve the name of the EXE from the LNK file and call the EXE using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Run`

Here is how you can resolve the EXE location from the LNK files

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8d0f33a3-af4d-498f-a37b-e6fc84136c4a/

Answer (score 0):

try to midify this example, it enables different options on different columns:

```
//Define different context menus for different columns
private ContextMenu contextMenuForColumn1 = new ContextMenu();
private ContextMenu contextMenuForColumn2 = new ContextMenu();

Add the following line of code in the form load event:

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load all default values of controls 
    populateDataGridView();

    // Add context mneu items
    contextMenuForColumn1.MenuItems.Add("Make Active", new     EventHandler(MakeActive));
    contextMenuForColumn2.MenuItems.Add("Delete", new     EventHandler(Delete));
    contextMenuForColumn2.MenuItems.Add("Register", new     EventHandler(Register));
}

Add the following code to mouseup event of the gridview:

private void dataGridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Load context menu on right mouse click
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        hitTestInfo = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        // If column is first column
        if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 0)
            contextMenuForColumn1.Show(dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        // If column is second column
        if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex == 1)
            contextMenuForColumn2.Show(dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}
```

Similar questions on SO:

- [Add context menu in a datagrid view in a winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201816/add-context-menu-in-a-datagrid-view-in-a-winform-application)
- [right click context menu for datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagrid)

Comment: actually i want to move file from grid view to removable media.