# How can I make my Windows Forms program execute any of the SendTo shortcuts

Tags: c#, winforms, sendto

I want to be able to show the SendTo menu on a file list inside my program and then execute the SendTo shortcut or droptarget on the chosen file. It seems I can ShellExecute a .lnk file, but I need to know how to simulate dropping a specified file onto a droptarget, such as "Mail Recipient"

Comment: have a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150412/how-i-can-use-windowss-sendto-option-in-my-c-sharp-application-using-datagridvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using an "send to" menu entry is not more than calling the lnk with the selected file as additional parameter.

so you just have to shellexecute the .lnk and give your target

```
ShellExecute( 0, "open", lnkPath, targetfilePath, NULL, SW_SHOW );
```