# How to open the ContextMenuStrip just added?

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I added a ContextMenuStrip to my Form but *nowhere* in that form (that otherwise works perfectly, including adding record to database) can I right-click to display the context menu.

That is, when I run the Form application, anywhere in that form I right-click, it's as if I didn't right-click at all: **No menu shows up** (yes, I added to it menu items).

**What am I missing?**

[image]

Also, while at that, is there a way to make it display when right-clicking certain controls only?

(Note: my question is language neutral. Once I get the ContextMenuStrip to display, I think that I know how to [handle its events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202123/1731850))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

For the control I want the context menu to appear (e.g. DataGridView), I need to go to its `Behavior` property and select from a list box the already created ContextMenuStrip instance:

[image]

Comment: Creating a Context Menu on a DataGridView Mouse Click - [Programmatically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/contextmenuforgridview01162007124516PM/contextmenuforgridview.aspx).